# How to add a Hint to TextInputLayout without getting Render Problem?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Whenever I try to add a hint to `TextInputLayout`, I Get this Render Problem on Android Studio
Screenshot of the Error:
[image]

Render Proplem Disappears after Removing the Hint from the TextInputLayout

Screenshot:
[image]

StackTrace of the Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1113)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1080)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1030)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:991)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.CutoutDrawable.drawStrokeShape(CutoutDrawable.java:100)
at com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.draw(MaterialShapeDrawable.java:974)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.CutoutDrawable.draw(CutoutDrawable.java:89)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.draw(LayerDrawable.java:1018)
at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:22581)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22342)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22323)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22223)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21995)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22221)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21995)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22353)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22323)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.draw(TextInputLayout.java:4078)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22223)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21995)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1994)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22221)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21995)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22353)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22323)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1833)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22223)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21995)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1994)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22221)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21995)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22221)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21995)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22221)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21995)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:22353)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22323)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:553)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:450)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:120)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:137)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:119)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$12(RenderTask.java:992)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

XML of the TextEditInputLayout Dropdown:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/convert_from"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="100dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="100dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="100dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/convertFromAutoCompleteTextView"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:text="@string/kilogram_kg" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Things I Tried Doing..

1. Rebuilding The Project
2. Restarting the Android Studio
3. Invalidating the Cache and Restarting
4. Refreshing the Layout (Which was Suggested By Android Studio)

That's All I tried to Include everything which may help in Answering this Question but still if you need something, then please ask in the Replies :))

Comment: I think it only happens on android studio editor because sometimes it can't access your resource, but when you test on real device you will be fine, I think the font is causing the problem, try deleting it to see.

Comment: It is not dangerous! If you configure your view programmatically, sometimes android studio can't handle this case, it works fine only if you configure with xml